# PySimpleGUI: How can I display a result in my window?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How can I display a result in a window?
I'm using PySimpleGUI to make user interface and I'm trying to display the result in the window. I was using `sg.Output()` but I didn't like the look.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
         [sg.Text("Name: "), sg.Input()],
         [sg.Ok()]
]

window = sg.Window("Just a window", layout)

while True:
    events, values = window.read()
    name = values[0]
```

Now, how can I display the name in the window as a text? I don't want to use `sg.Output()`.

Comment: Are there no other text boxes available other than `sg.Output`.  Or are there parameters for it that will change its appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sg.Text` as the output of the result, set option `size` of `sg.Text` to `(maximum, 1)`, like `(40, 1)`, or `(0, 1)`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Name: "), sg.Input(key='INPUT')],
    [sg.Ok()],
    [sg.Text("", size=(0, 1), key='OUTPUT')]
]

window = sg.Window("Just a window", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Ok':
        name = values['INPUT']
        window['OUTPUT'].update(value=name)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a text box:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

output = sg.Text()
layout = [
         [sg.Text("Name: "), sg.Input()],
         [output],
         [sg.Ok()]
]

window = sg.Window("Just a window", layout)

while True:
    events, values = window.read()
    name = values[0]
    output.update(value=name)
```

Comment: If i type "Jack", just the "J" appear

Comment: I find the solution in the docs. https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/

Comment: @lucasestevam I think your comments belonged on the other answer.